# std::type_traits functions changed behavior in vs19 bug or error?

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits, visual-studio-2019

The following code worked fine before upgrading to vs19:

```
template <typename... Args> constexpr  Function Callback(std::function<void(Args...)> const f) {
    return [=]() {
      GlobalVar=sum((std::is_base_of<BaseC,std::remove_pointer<std::remove_reference<Args>::type>::type>::value)...); 
       f((static_cast<Args>(GetVar))...); };
};}
```

The code is for a template function with function argument which returns a lambda to execute the argument with the values of GetVar (which is a class instance with overloaded operators), but just after setting a global var to the number of arguments the function will get which will have a base class BaseC or a pointer or a reference of it.

Now its throwing these errors:

```
Error   C2275    'std::remove_reference<int>::type': illegal use of this type as an expression  
Error   C2275    'std::remove_pointer<_Ty>::type': illegal use of this type as an expression    
Error   C2275    'std::remove_reference<char *>::type': illegal use of this type as an expression   
Error   C2955    'std::remove_pointer': use of class template requires template argument list   
Error   C2955    'std::is_base_of': use of class template requires template argument list
Error   C2923    'std::remove_pointer': 'std::remove_reference<int>::type' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'    
Error   C2923    'std::is_base_of': 'std::remove_pointer<_Ty>::type' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Derived'
```

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the full error messages from the compiler.

Comment: You might want to add some « type name » keyword and here there

Comment: Adding typename to every place solved the errors in exchange for making it less readable.  Never understood the need for it. Thanks anyway!